# autoloader Fatal error: Class not found, PSR-4

Tags: php, model-view-controller, composer-php, psr-4

Composer does not autoload class.

My composer file:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "core\\" : "/src/core/",
            "Rec\\RecipBundle\\Entity\\" : "/src/Rec/RecipBundle/Entity/",
            "Rec\\RecipBundle\\Controller\\" : "/src/Rec/RecipBundle/Controller/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "src/core/App.php",
            "src/core/View.php",
            "src/core/Controller.php"
        ]
    }
}
```

The generated classmap is wrong. For example,
C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.6.20-0\apache2\htdocs\www\Plan2own\vendor\composer\autoload_psr4.php

```
$vendorDir = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
$baseDir = dirname($vendorDir);

return array(
    'core\\' => array('/src/core'),
    'Rec\\RecipBundle\\Entity\\' => array('/src/Rec/RecipBundle/Entity'),
    'Rec\\RecipBundle\\Controller\\' => array('/src/Rec/RecipBundle/Controller'), );
```

If i try to load class Home i will get the error that file does not exist, although it exist. For example in 
C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.6.20-0\apache2\htdocs\www\Plan2own\src\core\App.php

```
namespace src\core;
use Rec\RecipBundle\Controller\Home;
class App{
public function __construct(){
$home = new Home(); //gives error
} }
```

In order to work, i have to correct autoload_psr4.php manually. How to generate correctly automaticaly? The corrected working version has baseDir prepended in C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.6.20-0\apache2\htdocs\www\Plan2own\vendor\composer\autoload_psr4.php:

```
return array(
    'core\\' => array($baseDir . '/src/core'),
    'Rec\\RecipBundle\\Entity\\' => array($baseDir .'/src/Rec/RecipBundle/Entity'),
    'Rec\\RecipBundle\\Controller\\' => array($baseDir .'/src/Rec/RecipBundle/Controller'), );
```